# Macrovision защита на Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

Подскажите, можно ли активировать Macrovision Protection на Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Это для защиты видео?

Comment: @gil9red, да, чтобы с аналового выхода видеопоток в внеполосных данных был с этим _мусором_ для защиты от копирования :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, никак. Ребята с Raspberry Pi говорят, что MV требует купить лицензию, чтобы использовать их технологию, поэтому... они ее не используют ))

https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1011